# CTLineGetTypographicBounds in iOS -- ascent and descent are always coming back as zero

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-text, ctlineref

In an iOS category on NSAttributedString, I have the following:

```
CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)self);
CGFloat ascent;
CGFloat descent;
double length = CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &ascent, &descent, NULL);
    // at this point, ascent and descent always come back as zero.
```

According to the docs, it appears that these should be the ascent and descent of the line.  But they aren't.

The width is not returning zero.

That said, if I then draw the line, it draws just fine.

Am I missing something?